# É possível ter mais de uma regra CSS para uma "img" em uma "div"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Como aplicar duas (ou mais) regras CSS a elementos `img` de dentro de uma `div`?

Uso o editor TinyMCE e quando faço envio de uma imagem para postagem ou mensagens (pms) tenho que setar em uma medida especifica para cada coisa, senão as imagens "estouram" as `divs`.

Aprendi a setar um valor de exibição padrão com CSS mas todas as imagens ficam com este valor independente de serem *landscape* ou *portrait* :(

Gostaria, se houver como, setar regras CSS distintas com base nas dimensões das imagens, fazendo as imagens *landscape* terem um padrão enquanto imagens *portrait* assumissem outro valor de padrão de exibição.

Comment: Como é o espaço que você tem para as imagens? "Nichos" de largura e altura fixas, onde as imagens precisam se encaixar independente do aspecto (portrait ou landscape)?

Comment: @bfavaretto as imagens são armazenadas no banco de dados e depois exibidas em uma div...juntamente com o conteúdo (textos, links, smilles, etc...) acontece que se eu setar um valor padrão uma ou outra ficar desproporcional pq acabarei fazendo imagens portrait serem exibidas como landscape por exemplo :( por isso acho(?) que java poderia fazer essa analize e aplicar regras por proporção ou porcentagem só não sei como.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode verificar o tamanho de cada imagem e atribuir um estilo utilizando `JQuery` da seguinte forma:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    if ($(this).width() > $(this).height()){
        //$(this).css();
    }else if ($(this).width() < $(this).height()){
        //$(this).css();
    }else{ //quando a largura e altura forem iguais:
        //$(this).css();
    }
});
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, em parte o que vç escreveu funciona faço width, height e left numa boa porém...se faço um else ou outro if o segundo parametro não funciona, só funciona o primeiro. Sabes me dizer como posso fazer o else funcionar tbm ?

Comment: @LauroMoraes não entendi muito bem o seu problema ao usar else, era para funcionar, se puder faça uma pergunta com o seu problema ou edite esta mesma pergunta. Mas creio que a solução que bfavaretto apresentou seja mais apropriada para o seu problema, com `max-width` e `max-height` você limita o tamanho da imagem que entra e não quebra o seu layout.

Comment: a minha pergunta é esta mesmo mas editaram ela retirando a final que dizia: "com javascript". Entendes duas regras css via java. Como voçê postou: se o comprimento for maior que a largura aplica-se uma regra css (wid, hei, lef) orém queria fazer duas então faria um "else" neste exemplo que vç postou...porém o "else" não funcionou. mesmo assim grato vou continuar tentando :)

Comment: @LauroMoraes incluí no código o else.

Comment: @LauroMoraes haviam removido o `java` da pergunta porque na verdade se chama `javascript`, `java` é outra linguagem.

Comment: o q vç postou salvou meu projeto rsrsr Thanks Man! Segue o link do exemplo de como ficou [link]http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/Ma8aR/2/ !!!EDITADO: não sei pq quando marco seu nome com @ não aparece aqui Paulo Maciel

Comment: Você não consegue me marcar porque não precisa marcar o autor da resposta. Que bom que funcionou! Abraços

Answer (score 3):

Com CSS você pode fazer as imagens se ajustarem automaticamente a uma área de dimensões fixas. Por exemplo, numa área de 400px por 300px:

```
img {
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: sim era essa a propriedade css al qual eu estava usando porém todas as imagens que vierem na postagem ou mensagem terão o mesmo tamanho não importando qual seja. Note: se eu setar um tamanho unico ou ele sera largura maio que comprimento, comprimento maior que largura  ou dimenssões iguais desse modo inevitavelmente perco uma das caracteristicas da imagem (ou landscape ou portrait) entendes?

Comment: E a largura corresponde a 550px normalmente fotos por exemplo são maiores :(

Comment: @LauroMoraes Não estou entendendo o problema, esse css faz as imagens se ajustarem sem distorcer. Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/8CH4r/